# Separating channels from an RGBA image using cuda (can't show full image)

Tags: c++, image, opencv, cuda

I'm trying to separate the channels from an image using cuda. The program outputs three images corresponding to channels. I'm getting the correct output but it is showing only a part of the image channels.

Here's my code:

```
  // main.cpp
  void separateHelper(const uchar4 *d_rgbaImage, uchar4 *d_channel, const int numRows, const int numCols,int channel);

  std::string file_name = "test.jpg";
  cv::Mat image, rgbaImage;
  int numRows(){ return rgbaImage.rows; };
  int numCols(){ return rgbaImage.cols; };

  int main(){

  uchar4 *h_rgbaImage, *h_red, *h_green, *h_blue;
  uchar4 *d_rgbaImage, *d_red, *d_green, *d_blue;
  cv::Mat red, green, blue;
  cv::Mat redChannel, greenChannel, blueChannel;

  image = cv::imread(file_name.c_str(),CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
  if (image.empty()){
      std::cerr << "error loading image";
      system("pause");
      exit(1);
  }

  cv::cvtColor(image,rgbaImage, CV_BGR2RGBA);
  //create space for output
  red.create(numRows(), numCols(), CV_8UC3);
  cv::cvtColor(red, redChannel, CV_BGRA2RGBA);
  green.create(numRows(), numCols(), CV_8UC3);
  cv::cvtColor(green, greenChannel, CV_BGRA2RGBA);
  blue.create(numRows(), numCols(), CV_8UC3);
  cv::cvtColor(blue, blueChannel, CV_BGRA2RGBA);

  h_rgbaImage = (uchar4*)rgbaImage.ptr<unsigned char>(0);
  h_red = (uchar4*)redChannel.ptr<unsigned char>(0);
  h_green = (uchar4*)greenChannel.ptr<unsigned char>(0);
  h_blue = (uchar4*)blueChannel.ptr<unsigned char>(0);

  //allocate memory on device
  const int numPixels = numCols()*numRows();
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_rgbaImage,sizeof(uchar4) * (numPixels + 500)));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_red, sizeof(uchar4) * (numPixels + 500)));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_green, sizeof(uchar4) * (numPixels + 500)));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_blue, sizeof(uchar4) * (numPixels + 500)));

  //copy image from host to device
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_rgbaImage, h_rgbaImage, sizeof(uchar4) * numPixels, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

  //call helper function of kernel
  separateHelper(d_rgbaImage, d_red, numRows(), numCols(),1);
  separateHelper(d_rgbaImage, d_green, numRows(), numCols(),2);
  separateHelper(d_rgbaImage, d_blue, numRows(), numCols(),3);

  //copy results back to host
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(h_red, d_red, sizeof(uchar4) * numPixels, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(h_green, d_green, sizeof(uchar4) * numPixels, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(h_blue, d_blue, sizeof(uchar4) * numPixels, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

  //change RGBA to BGR
  cv::cvtColor(redChannel,red,CV_RGBA2BGR);
  cv::cvtColor(greenChannel,green,CV_RGBA2BGR);
  cv::cvtColor(blueChannel,blue,CV_RGBA2BGR);

  cv::namedWindow("RED", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  cv::imshow("RED", red);
  cv::namedWindow("GREEN", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  cv::imshow("GREEN", green);
  cv::namedWindow("BLUE", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  cv::imshow("BLUE", blue);
  cv::waitKey(0);

  cudaFree(d_rgbaImage);
  cudaFree(d_red);
  cudaFree(d_green);
  cudaFree(d_blue);
  return 0;
}
```

Here's my GPU code:

```
// kernel.cu
__global__ void separateChannels(const uchar4* d_rgbaImage,uchar4* d_channel, int numRows, int numCols, int channel){
  int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
  if (x >= numCols || y >= numRows)
      return;
  int index = numRows * y + x;
  if (channel == 1){
      d_channel[index].x = d_rgbaImage[index].x;
      d_channel[index].y = 0;
      d_channel[index].z = 0;
  }
  else if (channel == 2){
      d_channel[index].x = 0;
      d_channel[index].y = d_rgbaImage[index].y;
      d_channel[index].z = 0;
  }
  else if (channel == 3){
      d_channel[index].x = 0;
      d_channel[index].y = 0;
      d_channel[index].z = d_rgbaImage[index].z;
  }
  d_channel[index].w = 255;
}

void separateHelper(const uchar4 *d_rgbaImage, uchar4 *d_channel,
    const int numRows, const int numCols, int channel){


  //set grid and block size
  int blockWidth = 32;
  const dim3 blockSize(blockWidth, blockWidth, 1);
  const dim3 gridSize(((numCols)/32 + 1 ), ((numRows)/32 + 1), 1);
  //call kernel
  separateChannels <<<gridSize, blockSize >>>(d_rgbaImage, d_channel, numRows, numCols, channel);

  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());
}
```

Error: Only a part of the image (red, green and blue channel images) is shown as output.

Comment: I'll recommend you to avoid using conditionals in kernel functions if possible. Every branch will be executed by SM  during run-time, which would definitely lower your performance.

Comment: @pSoLT: There is no divergent code paths in that kernel. channel is a runtime constant. The kernel is basically optimal, given what it does.

Comment: @talonmies I agree, my bad - I didn't read carefully enough :) But it wouldn't hurt to pass channel as an int3 and avoid all this conditionals.

Comment: Comment formatting

Answer (score 1):

I assume that it's either not enough threads assigned to perform the task or you confused x and y coordinates. In general the y-wise stripes are assigned with columns and x-wise stripes with rows. Each row contains `numColumns` elements and each column contains `numRows` elements. When you allocate threads you follow that logic:

```
int blockWidth = 32;
const dim3 blockSize(blockWidth, blockWidth, 1);
const dim3 gridSize(((numCols)/32 + 1 ), ((numRows)/32 + 1), 1);
```

but when you calculate the index you don't. Shouldn't

```
int index = numRows * y + x;
```

be:

```
int index = numColumns * y + x;
```

?

Comment: There is also (probably) out of bounds memory access in the kernel

Comment: no out of bounds issues in OP's code if parameters are well defined, since an early check is so ensure that the x & y values are less than the max resolution dimensions of the image. At some point a thread will always be out of bounds, but OP seemingly has the covered.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting only a part of the image channels because your grid dimensions are wrong. You need to replace numCols and numRows here:

```
 const dim3 gridSize(((numCols)/32 + 1 ), ((numRows)/32 + 1), 1);
```

Like this:

```
const dim3 gridSize(((numRows)/32 + 1 ), ((numCols)/32 + 1), 1);
```

And there is no need to add extra 500 here:

```
checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_blue, sizeof(uchar4) * (numPixels + 500)));
```

Answer (score -1):

I am so exciting that I just solved my problem!

My case is, C++ code result is correct, but GPU code result only show quarter of full image. 
That is because when cudaMemcpy from device to host, I set wrong parameters 'size'.

//cudaMemcpy( h_result, d_result, imagesize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

//cudaMemcpy( h_result, d_result, imagesize*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

sizeof(float) is exactly 4 bytes! So I only got quarter of full image.

REMEMBER multiply sizeof(data type).

Hope my answer be useful:)